# Wix Installer - how can I show the value of [Manufacturer] in the install path?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm trying to create an installer with a UI, using WiX.

My INSTALLFOLDER is set up using this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
           Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder"
               Name="[Manufacturer]">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER"
                 Name="[ProductName]" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

In the <Product> section, I'm defining:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"
          Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
```

When I run the installer and get to the Destination Folder panel, I see:

```
Install Service to: 
C:\Program Files\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\
```

How can I make it evaluate the variables for display?

**Note**: if I leave them, and click Next, Install and Finish it works.  It just looks bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define your variables in a config file.

For example, create a file named config.wxi containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Include>
    <?define Manufacturer = "Company Name" ?>
    <?define ProductName = "Product Name" ?>
  </Include>
```

Then reference the variables in your .wxs file using `$(var.Manufacturer)` and `$(var.ProductName)`.

Answer (score 43):

Binder variables can make this very easy without needing to mess around defining preprocessor variables.  It'd go a lot like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The `!(bind.)` syntax is documented in the `Linker (light)` topic in WiX.chm.

Comment: It doesn't appear that this works when an instance transform is applied -- I still get the default ProductName when installing a different instance.

Comment: @arathorn Have you got solution for Instance Transform? I have similar issue and get default product name when i applied instance transform.

Comment: Sadly for me this just spits out the string value "!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" when assigned to Product/@Manufacturer